# Using the alpha in Babylon mesh color vertices

Tags: alpha, babylonjs

This seems like it should be simple but nothing is working. I am setting colors for each vertex in a mesh using applyToMesh with a VertexData object. I have a simple StandardMaterial, no textures. I am trying to make certain vertices transparent if they appear over something else, so I set the "a" in the rgba colors to 0.5. But the mesh is still rendering opaque. I tried the following unsuccessfully:

material.hasAlpha = true

material.needAlphaBlending(true)

material.needAlphaBlendingForMesh(true)

material.alphamode = BABYLON.Engine.ALPHA_COMBINE;

mesh.visibility = 0.9999 to force alpha blending

Answer (score 0):

I made a small demo using multi materials and transparency :

https://www.babylonjs-playground.com/#2Q4S2S#199

the first (sub) material is using a png with a transparency channel. If you set the hasAlpha to true, and use the alpha channel from the diffuse texture, you can get transparency:

```js
var material0 = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial("mat0", scene);
material0.diffuseTexture = new BABYLON.Texture("/textures/down.png", scene);
material0.diffuseTexture.hasAlpha = true;
material0.useAlphaFromDiffuseTexture = true;
```

On the second material I am using a diffuse color and setting the alpha to 0.5 . setting the material backface culling to false will show the "back face" of the mesh as well:

```js
var material1 = new BABYLON.StandardMaterial("mat1", scene);
material1.diffuseColor = new BABYLON.Color3(0, 0, 1, 0.5);
material1.alpha = 0.5;
material1.backFaceCulling = false
```

Comment: This doesn't let me quickly turn specific vertices of the map on or off though. the point is that the mesh is dynamically changing each frame and various pixels are rapidly becoming opaque and transparent

Answer (score 0):

Try mesh.hasVertexAlpha = true
This enabled the alpha for me. but it poses some problem with the z-index buffering of the mesh.